# Как получить вложенные папки Яндекс Диска API?

Tags: php, yandex-disk

Как получить список вложенных директорий (папок) Яндекс Диска API?

Пробовал таким образом:

```
use Yandex\Disk\DiskClient;

$diskClient = new DiskClient();
 //Устанавливаем полученный токен
$diskClient->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
$diskClient->setServiceScheme(DiskClient::HTTPS_SCHEME);
//Получаем список файлов из директории
$dirContent = $diskClient->directoryContents('/');

// выводим все папки
foreach ($dirContent as $dirItem) {
    if ($dirItem['resourceType'] == 'dir') {
        echo  $dirItem['displayName']. '<br>';
    }
}
```

Имена директорий получил, а как получить имена вложенных директорий?

Comment: Могу предположить, что вам нужно использовать в цикле запрос к `directoryContents()` с указанием ранее полученного в цикле подкаталога.

Comment: можно пример? ввиде кода

Comment: не уверен, но что-то типа https://pastebin.com/zk5YGZv8

Comment: интересный вариант, спасибо)

Comment: но так не работает... directoryContents имеет 3 параметра, $path,  $offset, $amount

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для работы с яндекс диском один из написанных под него PHP SDK.

раз: https://github.com/jack-theripper/yandex

два: https://github.com/leonied7/yandex-disk-api

Во втором есть целый объект для работы с директориями всеми возможными образами:
https://github.com/leonied7/yandex-disk-api/wiki/Directory-Item

Насколько я могу судить по предыдущим вопросам здесь касательно яндекс диска - использование SDK убережет вас от дальнейших вопросов и "непоняток" из-за скудной документации по API на данный момент.